# Unobtrusive validation for integers with MVC3 and jQuery

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, unobtrusive-validation

Unobtrusive validation does not distinguish between data types. There's only 'number' validation that MVC adds to all numeric fields.

This has an unwanted effect of 1.2345 being a valid integer. When you submit, MVC binder cannot parse the value. So instead of getting a client-side error you get it from server.

What is the best way of solving this? Are there existing solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here's what I did.

Wrote my own EditorTemplate for Int32 (Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Int32.cshtml):

```
@model int?           
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString() : "", new { data_val_integer = "Field must be an integer" })
```

Added a validation adapter (run this on $(document).ready:)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('integer',
    function (value, element, params) {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || isInteger(value);
    });

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("integer", [],
    function (options) {
        options.rules['integer'] = {};
        options.messages['integer'] = options.message;
    });
```

Wrote Javascript function `isInteger` that looks like this

```
function isInteger(value) {
    return parseInt(value, 10) == value;
}
```

Now integer fields give a nice message "Field must be an integer" if you type anything with decimal dot in it.

Will be glad to hear of a better way.